# Android - Send notification with id

Tags: android, notifications

Please excuse my English, I'm French :

I've got a question about android notifications...
There is an inbox on my app and user is notified when he received a new notified.
When he click on the notification, I want to open the right activity with the right conversation so I've to pass an ID.

I've made a lot of search but I can't find...
Coul'd you help me please ?

Here my code :

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText(text);

    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, LandingActivity.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add the ID as an extra to your resultIntent. `resultIntent.putExtra("id", id);` Then you'll need to retrieve that ID value in your LandingActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you could save the ID of the conversation in the Intent that will launch your app. You do this by using extras:

```
resultIntent.putExtra("conversationID", "234553");
```

Then, in your MainActivity, you handle the case where the user has clicked on your notification:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("conversationID");
    //Display conversation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your question right: If you want to start different Activities according to something you received, you have to make different Intents for those cases.

If you always want to open your LandingActivity and pass data to it, add them as extras to your Intent, see [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android).